# Can I use a Vlookup to get a match, and then go one roow further

Tags: excel, indexing, excel-formula, vlookup, matching

I have a table with data that looks like this

```
food         value
apple         3
banana        1
pair          382
```

For my formula, I don't know the order of the data. I know that I want the value for whatever value is below banana.

Can I use a vlookup to get the value 382?

This is what I tried- `vlookup("banana", A1:B4, 2, false)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `index` and `match` as below

```
=index(b:b, match("banana", a:a,0) + 1)
```